# IOS database app(phonegap)- working on simulator but not working on device

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, sqlite

I build an iphone app using phonegap. I am using sqlite3 db to store the data locally. The app is working perfectly on simulator but gives error on actual ios device. It is throwing "`Could not prepare statement (1 no such table: table_name)`" error code for the same is Code=5.

Do i have to install sqlite plugin on ios device? The app is in a testing stage. I followed steps provided in [this](https://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-running-your-app-ios-device), to install the app on ios device.

What am I missing here?

Update:
This is the piece of code I'am using. My db resides at location

> /Users/imac/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/4C7CC11A-8938-479F-B810-86121D3311B7/Library/WebKit/Local Storage/File_0

And on the device it resides at

> AppData/Library/WebKit/Local Storage/File_0

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


        <title>Books | Categories</title>

        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

          var db;
          var shortName = 'Books';
          var version = '1.0';
          var displayName = 'BooksDB';
          var maxSize = 200000;
          function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
          alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code);
          }

          function successCallBack() {
              alert("DEBUGGING: success");

          }

          function nullHandler(){
              alert('null handler');
          };

          function onBodyLoad(){

              if (!window.openDatabase) {
                  alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
                  return;
              }
              db = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
              alert('db open');
              ListDBValues();
          }

          function ListDBValues() {
            var ArrayAlphabet=new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
            $('.container').empty();

            for (var i = 0; i < ArrayAlphabet.length; i++) {

            data='<div class="order" id="'+ArrayAlphabet[i]+'"></div>';

            load_books(ArrayAlphabet[i]);
            $('.container').append(data);
            data="";
            }
            return;
         }

          function load_books(bookTitleAlphabet)
          {

              if (!window.openDatabase) {
                  alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
                  return;
              }

            db.transaction(function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM books where book_title like "'+bookTitleAlphabet+'%" order by book_title desc;', [],
            function(transaction, result) {if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
            $('#'+bookTitleAlphabet).html(bookTitleAlphabet);

            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            var data;
            var row = result.rows.item(i);
            data="<a href='details.html?id="+row.book_id+"'> <div class='book'>";        
            data +="<div class='book_img'><img src="+row.book_thumb_location+"></div>";          
            data +="<div class='book_detail'>";
            data +="<div class='title'>"+row.book_title+"</div>";
            data +="<div class='author'>"+row.book_author+"</div>";
            data +="</div>";
            data +="<div class='clear'>";
            data +="</div>";
            data +="</div>";
            data +="</a>";       
            var tempId='#'+bookTitleAlphabet;    
            $(tempId).append(data);

            tempId="";

            }}
            if (result.rows.length==0)
            {
            var tempId='#'+bookTitleAlphabet;

            $(tempId).hide();
            }

            },errorHandler);},errorHandler,nullHandler);

            return;

        }
       </script>

</head>    
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">                 
  <div id="wrapper">            
    <div class="overflow_hide">
    </div>                         
    <div class="menu">                                 
      <div class="header">                    
        <div class="back">
          <a href="index.html">
            <input class="gobutton" type="button" value="Back" ></a>
        </div>                    
        <div class="list_book">BOOKS
        </div>                    
        <div class="settings">
          <a href="index.html">
            <input class="gobutton" type="button" value="Home" ></a>
        </div>                                   
      </div>                                 
      <div class="container">                                                                                
        <div class="clear">
        </div>                
      </div>                                                          
    </div>                         
    <div class="opac">                
      <a href="about.html">
        <div class="opac1">About Us
        </div></a>                               
      <a href="search.html">
        <div class="opac1">Search
        </div></a>                            
    </div>                         
    <div class="clear">
    </div>        
  </div>            
</body>
</html>
```

Is this because the app cannot find the db?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED/NEW ANSWER:**
As [the article here](http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/copy-prepopulated-sqlite-db-with-phonegap/) points out, you will likely have to do some work in XCode itself. As you correctly noted, the pathing to the database is different for pre-populated versus runtime-created databases. In short, your modifications will look for the pre-populated database and move it to the expected location/folder when it is detected. The nice thing: this will happen before your code begins to execute (javascript) so your existing code won't be "aware" that this even happened.

It is worth noting that the post I am referring you to goes past this and excludes the item from backup to iCloud. You will have to make a judgment call on whether you want to do that or not. It is pre-populated does not mean you wish to NOT back up that database nor does it make the leap (as the author does) that the pre-populated database is likely "large".

**OLD ANSWER:**
The error does not seem to indicate that it is having difficulty with SQLite itself, but a problem with a specific table not existing.

This typically happens when you are testing (via simulator) and at some point hit the appropriate code that performs the CREATE statement for the table. Then, later on, you get accustomed to that table being there and accidentally disconnect the schema-checking or table-existance-checking code. Since the table exists already, your simulator continues on about and never tries to re-create that table. When you go to run it on the actual device, however, that CREATE code never executes and falls into an area where you expect the table to exist - which causes the error.

Since you haven't posted any code, this is all conjecture on my part. If you want me to take a look, I would be happy to.

Comment: Yes I'am using pre-populated sqlite3 Db in my application.

Comment: Hi @Matt Ray, I have updated my questoin. Please take a look.

Comment: Hey there, @user1650891. I updated my answer based on this and approeciate the additional information!